# FFmpeg extracting current frame time stamp

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, timestamp

I need to extract frames in certain interval of the video, (eg from 40 sec to 50 sec).
Working in c++.
First I am getting position where I need to start reading

```
static double t = 10 ;//time in seconds
int64_t timestamp = t * AV_TIME_BASE; //destination time
av_seek_frame( pFormatContext , -1 ,  timestamp + pFormatContext->start_time ,AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD );
```

Then I using av_read_frame to get all sequential frames. 
The problem that I have is that I dont know when to stop. How can I check that I reached my end interval (eg 50 sec) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find frames per second and then use that number to calculate exact time of each frame as

```
frame_absolute_time = frame_number / FPS
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, generally this method is working. But there is a problem, av_seek_frame, returns last keyframe before the timestamp. Therefore I starting to count my 10 seconds a bit earlier ,and as a result I can miss some frames at the end (around 49...) of the interval. Any way to solve this ? Thanks

Comment: Not sure, except if there's an API call to get frame index for the frame actually sought to...

Answer (score 7):

`av_read_frame()` will give you a PTS (Presentation Time Stamp). It is AVPacket's member `pts`. Perhaps that value can help you decide when to stop reading.